# In Scala what is the most efficient way to remove elements in a list based on being similar to another element?

Tags: list, scala, loops, filter

I have a long list of objects around 300, with each object in the list having this data structure:

```
case class MyObject(id: String,
                    name: String,
                    colour: String,
                    price: Int
                    height: Int
                    width: Int,
                    desc: String)
```

I can’t work out what is the best way to go through the list and for each object remove any other object that has the same name, colour, price, height and width. Note that this isn’t a simple dedupe as the ids and desc can be different. The input and output need to remain `List[MyObject]` and I do not know beforehand which objects are the duplicated ones.

This is my initial solution which works, but not sure its the most efficient way of doing it when it comes to dealing with large list.

```
def removeDuplicates(originalList: List[MyObject]): List[MyObject] = {

  def loop(remaining: List[MyObject], acc: List[MyObject]): List[MyObject] = {
    remaining match {
      case head :: tail =>
        val listOfDuplicates = tail.filter{ x =>
          x.name == head.name &&
          x.colour == head.colour &&
          x.price == head.price &&
          x.height == head.height &&
          x.width == head.width
        }

        val deDupedTail = tail.filter(!listOfDuplicates.contains(_))

        loop(deDupedTail, acc ::: listOfDuplicates)
      case Nil => acc
    }
  }
  val listOfDuplicateObjects = loop(originalList, List())
  originalList.filter(!listOfDuplicateObjects.contains(_))
}
```

Comment: That's a very good start. You can make it more efficient by accumulating iterated values into a hashed data structure like a `Set`, which will get you O(1) searching rather than O(n).

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if it's most efficent, but IMHO it's elegant:

```
originalList.distinctBy(o => (o.name, o.colour, o.price, o.height, o.width))
```

Comment: Holy cow it's built in. Scala's massive collection library never ceases to amaze me.